# Create User-Defined Function to Calculate Quater from Datetime Column (KQL / Kusto / Azure Data Explorer)

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

The first query below produces the correct output; however, my dataset has many datetime columns in which I would like to calculate the quarter.  I would like to produce the same output using a user-defined function.  I have attempted to create the function however I am getting a 'General_BadRequest' error and cannot figure out why. Can someone help correct my function below?

Also, is there a function already built into Kusto that calculates quarters?

**Working Query - Output is Correct**

```
range Date from todatetime('2021-01-01') to todatetime('2021-12-31') step 7d
| extend CaseMethod=case(
getmonth(Date) between (7 .. 9), 1,
getmonth(Date) between (10 .. 12), 2,
getmonth(Date) between (1 .. 3), 3,
getmonth(Date) between (4 .. 6), 4, 0)
```

**Query with Function - Results in 'General_BadRequest'**

```
let QtrFunc = (x:datetime) {
toscalar(
datatable ( Qtr:long, Mo_Start:long, Mo_End:long )
[ 1, 7,  9,
  2, 10, 12,
  3, 1,  3,
  4, 4,  6  ]
| where getmonth(x) between (Mo_Start .. Mo_End)
| project Qtr ) } ;
range DateCol from todatetime('2021-01-01') to todatetime('2021-12-31') step 7d
| extend FunctionMethod=QtrFunc(DateCol)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I would like to produce the same output using a user-defined function.*

instead of using a `datatable` in your function, you could use the `case()` function:

```
let get_quarter = (dt:datetime) {
    case(monthofyear(dt) between (7 .. 9), 1,
         monthofyear(dt) between (10 .. 12), 2,
         monthofyear(dt) between (1 .. 3), 3,
         monthofyear(dt) between (4 .. 6), 4,
         0)
}
;
range col1 from datetime(2021-01-01) to datetime(2021-12-31) step 7d
| extend result = get_quarter(col1)
```

> *Also, is there a function already built into Kusto that calculates quarters?*

Different people may have different definitions for how the year is divided into quarters. For example: in your case, July to September is the 1st quarter, but in someone else's case, January to March is the first quarter.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for.  I didn't realize case would work in the function.  I was almost there ... lol